# How to write all data frames from a list to csv (conserving the name of the list)?

Tags: r

I am trying to write all the dataframes from a list to a csv conserving the name of the list and I am not sure what am i doing wrong. This is what I am trying as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189373/export-each-data-frame-within-a-list-to-csv) :

```
v1<-c(0:9)
v2<-c(10:19)
v3<-c(20:29)
v4<-c(30:39)
v5<-c(40:49)
v6<-c(50:59)

lista<- cbind(v1, v2, v3)
listb<- cbind(v4, v5, v6)
list<- list(lista, list)

for (i in seq_along(list)) {
filename = paste(names(list)[i], ".csv")
write.csv(data[[i]], filename)
}
```

However I get this error `Error in data[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. 
I know this has been asked before buy I have tried everything I could find. 
Many thanks!

Comment: `data` is a function. You cannot subset a function with `[[`. This is what the error message means.

Comment: `list` is also a function. It is a bad practice to save an object with a pre-defined function name in R.

Comment: It seems like you just made a typo by copying others' code without making the necessary change. Thus, I decided to close it as a duplicate.